# Combining an absolute path with a relative path in WiX 3.7

Tags: wix, wix3, wix3.7

I'm trying to use `RemoveFolderEx` to delete a folder one level up from my install folder upon uninstall of the app.  Here is what I have, but it's not working:

```
  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="MyAppBaseFolder" Name="MyAppID">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MyAppLauncher">
            <Directory Id="UPDATESCRIPTSFOLDER" Name="Scripts" />
            <Component Id="CleanupMainApplicationFolder" Guid="*">
              <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\MyApp ID\MyApp ID Windows Client" Name="Path" Type="string" Value="${path::getfullpath(path::combine([INSTALLFOLDER],'..\MyApp'))}" KeyPath="yes" />
              <util:RemoveFolderEx On="uninstall" Property="APPLICATIONFOLDER" />
            </Component>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
        <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="MyApp ID"/>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
```

The MSI will build fine, but when I run the setup it seems to be failing on the `RegistryValue` element and complaining about the ".." in the path.  The string I'm making is like: `"C:\Program Files (X86)\MyApp ID\MyAppLauncher\..\MyApp"`.  I need it to resolve to: `"C:\Program Files (X86)\MyApp ID\MyApp"`.

I'm not too familiar with the `${path:: ... }` stuff.  I saw a couple examples with `${path::combine()}` so I guess I assumed that would work with `getfullpath` in .NET.  Perhaps it does and my syntax is just wrong?

Thank you!

EDIT: Sorry, I got that `${path::combine...` stuff from [BUILDING WIX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/building_wix.htm) without fully reading what that article is doing.  It has nothing to do with a wxs file, it's for NAnt (as Rob mentioned below).  So I guess my question simply is this: how can I combine and resolve an absolute and relative path like `C:\Program files (X86)\MyApp ID\MyAppLauncher\..\MyApp`.  Thanks

EDIT2: Thanks again Rob, I was focusing so much on resolving the path I didn't even consider the most obvious solution, which was to simply reference a new `<Directory` element.  I now have it cleaning up 2 folders with the following code:

```
  <Property Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER">
    <RegistrySearch Key="SOFTWARE\MyApp ID\MyApp ID Windows Client" Root="HKLM" Type="raw" Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER_REGSEARCH" Name="Path" />
  </Property>

  <Property Id="PRINTERFOLDER">
    <RegistrySearch Key="SOFTWARE\MyApp ID\MyApp ID Printer" Root="HKLM" Type="raw" Id="PRINTERFOLDER_REGSEARCH" Name="Path" />
  </Property>
```

...

```
  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="MyAppBaseFolder" Name="MyAppID">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MyAppLauncher">
            <Directory Id="UPDATESCRIPTSFOLDER" Name="Scripts" />
            <Component Id="CleanupMainApplicationFolder" Guid="*">
              <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\MyApp ID\MyApp ID Windows Client" Name="Path" Type="string" Value="[LM_INSTALLFOLDER]" KeyPath="yes" />
              <util:RemoveFolderEx On="uninstall" Property="APPLICATIONFOLDER" />

              <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\MyApp ID\MyApp ID Printer" Name="Path" Type="string" Value="[LMP_INSTALLFOLDER]" />
              <util:RemoveFolderEx On="uninstall" Property="PRINTERFOLDER" />
            </Component>
          </Directory>
          <Directory Id="LM_INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MyApp" >
          </Directory>
          <Directory Id="LMP_INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MyAppPrinter" >
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
        <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="MyApp ID"/>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you have in the `RegistryValue/@Value` looks like NAnt or something. It isn't clear what interprets that but the Windows Installer will not. You have a couple options to get that registry value correct. First, change the `RegistryValue` element to look like:

```
<RegistryValue Root="HKLM"
               Key="SOFTWARE\MyApp ID\MyApp ID Windows Client"
               Name="Path"
               Type="string"
               Value="[MyAppBaseFolder]MyApp"
               KeyPath="yes" />
```

Alternatively, you could define "MyApp" in your Directory tree and reference it directly. That'd look a little like adding the following as a child of `MyAppBaseFolder` (peer of `INSTALLFOLDER`):

```
 <Directory Id='MyAppFolder' Name='MyApp' />
```

Then updating your `RegistryValue` element to look like:

```
<RegistryValue Root="HKLM"
               Key="SOFTWARE\MyApp ID\MyApp ID Windows Client"
               Name="Path"
               Type="string"
               Value="[MyAppFolder]"
               KeyPath="yes" />
```

I prefer the latter but that's just because I prefer using identifiers without concatenating strings.

Comment: Thanks a lot (again) Rob! I was just updating my post when you wrote your answer.  Indeed it is NAnt.  I guess I should read those articles a little closer before sticking random code into my XML :).  I'm going to try your suggestions right now.